# Datatype to store both Numeric and Alphabet in SQL - can Char store Both Type?

Tags: sql-server

I am currently using Char to store my data as alphabet. Now i need to change it to store both Numbers and Alphabets

For Example;

EmployeeID:

```
1.1234
2.JHOO
```

Comment: Why not try it and see? Or read the documentation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`CHAR` will store any characters in the encoding type you have set on the server.

This will normally include all ASCII letters and numbers, plus some more.

For Microsoft SQL server, documentation is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql

The relevant parts of documentation for MySQL are

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you should use a special datatype called sql_variant.

If you stores char such a datatype the internal storage for this value will be a varchar or nvarchar.

If you stores a number the internal type will be a number or an integer...

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE T (C sql_variant)

INSERT INTO T VALUES (123);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('hello');

SELECT *, CASE 
             WHEN TRY_CAST(C AS bigint) IS NOT NULL THEN 'INTEGER' 
             WHEN TRY_CAST(C AS NVARCHAR(max)) IS NOT NULL THEN 'STRING' 
          END AS DATATYPE
FROM   T;
```